# How to compare graphically the raw data to the fitted distribution

Tags: matlab, pdf, plot, histogram, data-fitting

I have a data series and estimated the parameters of the probability density function I wanted. It's a pdf that isn't in the MATLAB "distribution fitting" app and another that is but I modified to be exactly what I wanted.

The problem is when I'm doing the goodness of fit starting to compare the adjusted pdf with the empircal distribution.
I don't know if the y-axis is supposed to be in frequency but I'm doing it all in density.

What I've got:

[image: what I'm having]

The red line I'm supposed to have but flipped:

[image: the red line I'm supposed to have but flipped]

The thing is, in the first graph the normal is nicely enquadrated but the other two distribution are not. First, none was enquadrated but then I normalized the histogram:

```
histogram(DATAs,'Normalization','pdf')
```

But as you can see in the second graph the red one is supposed to be along with the histogram while on the first one is completely separated. (It's the same data, the only thing is that in the second one I estimated using the "distribution fitting" app with positive values and I plan to do a flip when passing to the first one).

I'm starting to think that the problem is when plotting the pdf. Do I need to adjust the pdf scale in order to have the second image in the first one?

Supposing that the parameters are correctly estimated. The pdf plot I did like this:

```
x_DATAs =linspace(minval1,maxval1,10000);
parmhat=[parmhat DATAs(1),parmhatDATAs(2),parmhatDATAs(3)];
y2_ DATAs = sgtpdf(x_DATAs ,parmhat,parmhat DATAs(4),parmhatDATAs(5));
plot(x_ DATAs ,y2_ DATAs , '--g')
```

I wanted to get something like this:

[image: what I aim to get]